# In C# if textBox contains character, return the meaning of the character into the Label

Tags: c#, textbox

How would you approach this... 
I would like to have a textbox where user would input certain characters like shown in this picture:

[image: Example]

And on the bottom of the textbox, I was thinking to have some `Label` controls that would correspond to the input of the textbox. For example, if user types AOC-STGF in the `TextBox`, `Label1` would display `"Add On Card"`, `Label2` would display `"Standard"`, `Label3` would display `"10GbE"`, `Label4` would display `"Fortville"` and so on...

Something along these lines:

[image: input/output]

I was thinking of a bunch of `if` statements, but that's not a good approach and it's lengthy. Also I would have to consider duplicate characters, for example you could have `"G"` mentioned twice in the `TextBox`.

Comment: You likely want Regex for this

Comment: While this could be done with substring, Regex is probably the way to go. I'd create a dictionary to keep track of the values of each snippet.

Comment: I'd use a combination of Regex to validate the type of string you're working with and then some function specific to that type of string would process each character or character set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I certainly would not use regex for this.  I would use a simple pipeline type approach where a set of processors each handle the next part of the message.  This works well because the process runs linearly.  The only problem we'd have here is if an optional step was able to yank the first character off the following step.  It appears that your data accounts for that.

First we define what a ParserStep would look like.  We use a list of Tuples for our data (char code, string), and a predicate for our TODO action:

```
public class ParserStep
{
    public Action<string> ToDo { get; set; }
    public List<Tuple<string, string>> Data { get; set; } = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
    public bool Optional { get; set; } = false;

    public string ProcessStep(string message)
    {
        foreach (var d in Data)
        {
            if (message.StartsWith(d.Item1))
            {
                ToDo(d.Item2);
                return message.Substring(d.Item1.Length);
            }
        }
        if (!Optional)
            throw new InvalidDataException();
        return message;
    }
}
```

Then we create a class that knows how to run steps and handles the trimming and finishing:

```
public class Parser
{
    public List<ParserStep> Steps { get; set; } = new List<ParserStep>();

    public void Run(string message)
    {
        foreach (var step in Steps)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((message)))
                return;
            message = step.ProcessStep(message);
            message = message.TrimStart('-');
        }
    }
}
```

So now we can build up ParserStep objects, set data on them, tell them what to do with the value of the code, and add them to a list.  Then we just hand those off to our Parser object that'll loop through them.

Here's a quick sample:

```
       var p = new Parser()
        {
            Steps =
            {
                new ParserStep()
                {
                    Data = { Tuple.Create("AOC", "Add On Card") },
                    ToDo = (a => Console.WriteLine($"Product Family = {a}")),
                    Optional = false
                },
                new ParserStep()
                {
                    Data =
                    {
                        Tuple.Create("S", "Standard"),
                        Tuple.Create("P", "Proprietary"),
                        Tuple.Create("C", "MicroLP"),
                        Tuple.Create("MH", "SIOM Hybrid"),
                        Tuple.Create("M", "Super IO")
                    },
                    ToDo = (a => Console.WriteLine($"Form Factor = {a}")),
                    Optional = false
                }
            }
        };
```

**Note that as the ToDo, I'm writing to a console.  This is where you would set the value on a label!**

Then we just call it like this:

```
p.Run("AOC-S");
```

This simple example has everything hard coded but you can easily modify to read from a database or whatever.  And finally, below is a complete .NET Core Console app to show the complete code working:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;

namespace CoreConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var p = new Parser()
            {
                Steps =
                {
                    new ParserStep()
                    {
                        Data = { Tuple.Create("AOC", "Add On Card") },
                        ToDo = (a => Console.WriteLine($"Product Family = {a}")),
                        Optional = false
                    },
                    new ParserStep()
                    {
                        Data =
                        {
                            Tuple.Create("S", "Standard"),
                            Tuple.Create("P", "Proprietary"),
                            Tuple.Create("C", "MicroLP"),
                            Tuple.Create("MH", "SIOM Hybrid"),
                            Tuple.Create("M", "Super IO")
                        },
                        ToDo = (a => Console.WriteLine($"Form Factor = {a}")),
                        Optional = false
                    }
                }
            };
            p.Run("AOC-S");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class ParserStep
    {
        public Action<string> ToDo { get; set; }
        public List<Tuple<string, string>> Data { get; set; } = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
        public bool Optional { get; set; } = false;

        public string ProcessStep(string message)
        {
            foreach (var d in Data)
            {
                if (message.StartsWith(d.Item1))
                {
                    ToDo(d.Item2);
                    return message.Substring(d.Item1.Length);
                }
            }
            if (!Optional)
                throw new InvalidDataException();
            return message;
        }
    }

    public class Parser
    {
        public List<ParserStep> Steps { get; set; } = new List<ParserStep>();

        public void Run(string message)
        {
            foreach (var step in Steps)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((message)))
                    return;
                message = step.ProcessStep(message);
                message = message.TrimStart('-');
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Cheers and thanks for giving me the exercise!

Comment: Thank you all for your responds... @TheSoftwareJedi... This is awesome, and it works for the items on the left from the first picture... however, if I try to extract the same info by typing AOC-MHIBF (like the text from the first picture on the right side), I wold get "Exception Underhanded" error. Any idea?

Comment: I think my comment above has to do with the fact that  under "Form Factor" there is a tuple for "M" and again one for "MH". And I think that throws an error

Comment: @jbegic I'll update the code - but you're right it needs to reverse the order of M and MH in the input data.  Other than that, it should be fine if built all the way out.

Comment: @jbedic actually, the Parser could order the Data of a step by Item1.Length before running the step and it would then not matter the order it was added.  I'll leave that as an exercise to you :)

Comment: Thank you. I'll see what I can do :-) I just started learning C# not to long ago but it's more inline with SQL Database. I have extended code with all the rest of "Characters" (see picture on top) and it works for certain items like "AOC-STGF-i2S" because it contains all items in order until the "7th Character" from the picture above. Now if I remove "F" and try to run AOC-STG-i2S. This would give me an error because it doesn't know how to skip "optional" items which is "4th Character" :-(

Comment: The ParserStep has a flag "Optional" that you can set.  I didn't set it in the example.  I just updated it to show how.  That should work if you set it to the ones that are Optional it will skip them if it can't find a match.

Comment: You are the Jedi for sure. Thank you so much with help on this. I have learned a lot from it.

Comment: One more question... Now in this Same Project, if I want to use lets say Form1 with textBox1 for input and let's say richTextBox1 for the output instead of Console. I would need some type of Console Redirection... Is that right?

Comment: @jbegic I would change the Console.WriteLine line of code to do whatever you need.  I was expecting you to make it textBoxWhatever.Text = ....